# Error Messages when calculating effect size for meta-analysis in R

Tags: r, typescript, effects

I am trying to conduct a meta-analysis in R using the esc package - specifically in Hedge's g from the mean and sd.

I'm new to R and completely lost.

Here's the code I used last:

```
esc::effect_sizes(iris[1:6,12], esc_mean_sd(),variable_x,fun = "mean_sd", es.type = c("d"))
```

I am attempting to calculate the effect size (Hedge's g from mean_sd of the raw data points) for a meta-anlysis.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question - but this last line of code game me an error of Error in data[, cols] : incorrect number of dimensions         prior to that I was getting errors of undefined column and Error in substr(fun, 1, 4) : argument "fun" is missing, with no default

Comment: Could you rewrite your question in such a way so that is reproducible to others. i.e. try to use the iris data set [data(iris)] Without common data it is very hard to track down errors.